# How do I use bash script to parse a JSON and run related commands according to the parsed results?

Tags: shell-script, curl, json

I have a JSON file (array) like this:

```
[
  {"name":"Joe","age":36},
  {"name":"John","age":14},
  {"name":"Linda","age":62}
]
```

And I want to parse it in shell, analyzing every item in the array, then to run a command for each item:

```
curl 'http://example.com/submit' -H --data 'name=[NAME]&age=[AGE]'
```

Which is, in this case:

```
curl 'http://example.com/submit' -H --data 'name=Joe&age=36'
curl 'http://example.com/submit' -H --data 'name=John&age=14'
curl 'http://example.com/submit' -H --data 'name=Linda&age=62'
```

I know how to do it with Node.jS but I really want to know how to achieve such operations in bash.

I am using `zsh` on `ubuntu`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON with shell scripting in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121718/how-to-parse-json-with-shell-scripting-in-linux) ... then use xargs

Comment: ```curl 'http://example.com/submit' -H --data 'name=[NAME]&age=[AGE]' | php -r 'var_dump(json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN)));' ```